# Is there a way to get the "parent" Spreadsheet which triggered the code?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that executes a code, i've attached it to some buttons in differents sheets and inside this code i need to get the sheet name that contains the buttom that triggered the script. Is there a way to get it?

I've coded this so far:

```
  let sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Escopo - Financeiro");

  var nomeDoc = sht.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var modulo = sht.getRange("B1").getValue();
```

So i need to change the  `.getSheetByName("Escopo - Financeiro")` code to fit my needs.

I was wondering if i could use some certain of "this" or "parent" statement, but i havent found it.

Comment: In your situation, when `let sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Escopo - Financeiro");` is modified to `let sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`, is it the result you expect? If you want to retrieve the sheet name of the active sheet, you can retrieve it by `const sheetName = sht.getSheetName();`. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, i've changed it and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Made it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since i've bounded my script to a button which is into an active spreadsheet, replacing the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Escopo - Financeiro");` part of the code to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();` solved the problem.